# Trotter product formula

Tags: matrices

What prevents me from writing :

$$
e^{A+B}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( e^{A/n}e^{B/n}\right)^n=\lim_{n \to \infty}  e^{nA/n}e^{nB/n}=e^Ae^B
$$

---

Edit:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( e^{A/n}e^{B/n}\right)^n= \lim_{n \to \infty} e^{A/n}e^{B/n} e^{A/n}e^{B/n} ... = \lim_{n \to \infty} e^{A/n} e^{A/n}e^{B/n} e^{B/n}...=\lim_{n \to \infty} e^{A}e^{B} 
$$

Comment: $(AB)^n = A^nB^n$ (your second equality) is only true for matrices that commute

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thanks you. Can you have a look at my edit and tell whats wrong?

Comment: Nothing has changed. You still assumed you could swap the order of the products.

Comment: @NinadMunshi So the products never become commutative? I see.